# CSS - How to select an element followed by another element that is contained within an element

Tags: css

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<blockquote>
    <p> ... </p>
    <br> //not this
    <br> //I want to select this
    <pre> ... </pre>
    <br> //not this
    <p> ... </p>
    <br> //not this
    <br> //I want to select this
    <p> ... </p>
    <br> //not this
    <p> ... </p>
    <br> //not this
</blockquote>
```

How do I select only the second `<br>` in a `<blockquote>`

I tried this:
`blockquote br+br {...}` but it didn't work

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* You need to further describe "didn't work".

Comment: @Anonymous it simply didn't select it. Is there anyway I can debug it/ get an error message?

Comment: Could you provide a working example demonstrating the problem? Not just {...}.

Comment: @Anonymous Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/3wxmhvxy/2/

Comment: @MargoEastham when I try your css selector with <p> tags, it works the way you want (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/3wxmhvxy/3/) which means it should be working the way you want... I think it's just a bit difficult to tell because the <br> elements are rendering 'invisibility'

Comment: @Daemedeor yes it apparently did! I thought it didn't because it's hard to see. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @MargoEastham btw, becareful, it'll select any after as well like <br> //not selected <br> //selected <br> //selected <br> //selected .... etc. <p>

Answer (score 1):

> How do I select only the second `<br>` in a `<blockquote>`

Just use `blockquote > br:nth-of-type(2)`. This would select only the second child `<br>` tag found in a blockquote element.

Your updated example:

```css
blockquote > br:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4> A text </h4>
    <br>
    <h4> Another text </h4>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4> Yet another text </h4>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
blockquote:nth-child(3) { } //index starts from 1
```

Comment: this is not a solution because this would select the second element, regardless of the type and not multiple second <br>s right after a <br>

Comment: @Daemedeor his original question stated he wanted to select the 3rd br element

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RJK my answer was to his original question, and my answer could have been able to solve his original question, blame the poster.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doing this:

```
blockquote br{...}
```

would add the style to all of the br tags inside the blockquote.
You should make a class and add only to the br you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a class selector for my `<br>` tag.

```
<blockquote>
    <p> ... </p>
    <br>
    <br class="here-it-is"> //this is selected
    <pre> ... </pre>
    <br> //this is not
    <p> ... </p>
</blockquote>
```

Then reference in your CSS: `br.here-it-is  { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
blockquote br:nth-of-type(2) {
   ... 
}
```

It will select the `nth` child of blockquote but only considering `br`, starting from 1.